# c# wpf button with variable as name? same colours in all buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, variables, button

Hello I have 2 questions.

This is my code: (kolLos make random number between 0 and 255)

```
    public int numer_prostokata = 1;

    private void Glowny_przycisk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a Button
        Button blueRectangle = new Button();
        blueRectangle.Content = numer_prostokata;
        var nazwa_batona = "s_b_" + numer_prostokata;
        blueRectangle.Name = nazwa_batona;

        MainWindow.Children.Add(blueRectangle);
        myColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos());
        blueRectangle.Background = myColor;


        numer_prostokata++;
    }
```

It almost work. Buttons are generating on click. They have different Contents, but... always the same color. Colors are changing after each Click, but all buttons have the same (for example all red or all blue)...

What I did wrong?

And second question:

name of Buttons is "s_b_" + number. It is in var "nazwa_batona". But when I use

```
nazwa_batona.Background = myColor;
```

- it doesn't work... What should I do?

I'm very begining in C#... I googled and searched many hours but didn't find answers...

Oh! There can be many buttons created and they can be in different places...

Comment: You need to show your code for `kolLos()`

Comment: Background property is of type Brush (you need SolidColorBrush for example).

Comment: I doubt the `kolLos()` has some local Random variable inside used to just generate a random byte. So each call to `kolLos()` will return the same random value, you need to define some global Random field instead or use different seek values for the random so that different values will be returned.

Comment: For WPF button, it should be a Brush, not a Color, right?

Comment: private byte kolLos()
        {

            int liczba = LiczbaLosowa.Next(0, 255);
            return Convert.ToByte(LiczbaLosowa.Next(0, 255));
        }

Comment: Colors are changed. For example: all buttons are white. after next click all buttons became red. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `myColor` is some class level `SolidColorBrush` since it isn't declared in the function. Given that, the following code simply changes the color of that brush, then assigns the brush to the new button instance:

```
 myColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos());
 blueRectangle.Background = myColor;
```

However, *every button has the same brush instance*, so when you change the color for the next button, all the previous ones change as well.

You need to create a *new* brush:

```
 SolidColorBrush backgorundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
 backgorundBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos());
 blueRectangle.Background = backgorundBrush;
```

Comment: That's right.

(to be honest, you made one mistake - in last line should be backgorundBrush instead of myColor)

`SolidColorBrush kolorbuttona = new SolidColorBrush();
            kolorbuttona.Color = Color.FromArgb(kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos(), kolLos());
            blueRectangle.Background = kolorbuttona;`

Comment: @PatrykGodowski Nice catch! sorry for the typo.

Comment: And the second question?

If buttons' name is "gummibears" and I have var name="gummibears" is it possible to use `name.Background` instead of `gummibears.Background`?

Comment: @PatrykGodowski Possible but not recommended. Look into `VisualTreeHelper`. Having a ton of named controls is generally a bad approach.